# Fill shapes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

I am very new to Illustrator (read: this is the first thing I have ever tried) and I am trying to do what I am sure is a very simple task.

[image]

Using the line segment tool I drew the above shapes and all that I want to do is fill the two quadrilaterals on the left and right with a solid color. I can't figure out how to do that, and I don't know the Illustrator vocabulary well enough to Google it.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. The vocabulary is "fill" googling for "illustrator fill color" you get the [manual entry](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/painting-fills-strokes.html). Which explains it well,  if not there is even a video below that explains this also, if reading does not happen to be your cup of tea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your line are joined each other. If not

1. Select your entire line(`Ctrl`+`A`) and go to Tool bar and select `Join tool` and click on all joints one by one
2. Now your all lines are joined, select the line and go tot again tool bar change
   Swap Fill and Stroke(`Shift`+`X`). Now your two quadrilaterals are filled with same color.
3. go to `windows`>`Pathfinder`, from the panel click on `Minus front`, two quadrilaterals will divide, now individually you can select object and change the color.

Done!